# Не корректный заголовок User-Agent

Tags: php, сервер, веб-сервер

Собрал слайдер, в котором есть условие проверки заголовка User-Agent и в зависимости мобильный это или нет отдавать нужную картинку. Почему на некоторых mac'ах этот заголовок отправляется как android 6.0, проверял в chrome 64, хотя на другой половине маков отправляется заголовок, который содержит macintosh. Причем эта ситуация возникает переодически, то они андройд отправляют, то они отправляют мак.

Comment: Проверять по юзерагенту это не очень хорошая идея, для разделения мобильного и немобильного вида лучше использовать CSS3 @media

Comment: Просто есть слайдер для мобилки и десктопа он отдает разные изображения. Не хорошо это грузить в 2 раза больше изображений и там и там (ладно для десктопа, инет все таки лучше, но от части). Может подскажите выход из этой ситуации. p.s. зачем тогда этот заголовок вообще существует если он так троит и как вы сказали не лучшая идея?

Comment: Заголовок может пригодиться только когда другие способы не работают и для подсчёта статистики использования браузеров, а в целом он бесполезен. Тот же CSS3 @media вполне позволит вам не грузить лишние картинки

Comment: Т.е. если написать @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {.selector {background-image: url(img-mobile.jpg)}} и второе где условие обратное min-width: 991px то оба изображения сразу грузиться не будут? Если так то я видимо где-то очень крупно просчитался когда изучал css3

Comment: Сейчас можно использовать picture и атрибут srcset. Вот подробное описание: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/

Comment: @Алексей сейчас проверил в Firefox, Chrome (в т.ч. на андроиде), Safari (в т.ч. на настоящем айфоне) и Edge — они лишнего не грузят. (IE грузит, но его на мобилках толком и нет) Я не в курсе, стандартизирует ли CSS загрузку или незагрузку лишнего, но, пока на мобилках доминирует Chrome, думаю, можно считать, что лишнее не грузится. Вышеупомянутый picture/srcset тоже годится, если уместен для вашего случая

Comment: @andreymal после того как ответил Вам второй раз, решил не ждать ответа и сразу полез проверять и тестить и меня все устроило. Просто предполагал, что media работают не так как ожидал. Казалось что они грузят все а потом из имеющегося выбирают нужное по условию и показывают. Но результат превзошел все мои ожидания. Совет с picture тоже очень заинтересовал(в свободное время даже потестил), но в моем случае был фон.